# Ajax jsonp data request - Asynchronous TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asynchronous

I am having an issue with a ajax request.

I am calling in a time API by using the following code. This works correctly:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=GMT&callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp', //We can only access this page API via JSONP
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.hour + ':' + data.minute + ':' + data.second);
    }
});
```

Sometimes I refresh the page and it will throw the following error (for the object):

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

If I change the above code to. It does not happen:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=GMT&callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp', //We can only access this page API via JSONP
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.hour + ':' + data.minute + ':' + data.second);
    }
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i think this code is correct and there is no issue with your code 
i'll try your code in my browser and it didn't show error that u just described

response that i get is : 13:11:14 
i didn't face such error in your code ...

but if u persist error then 
I think the problem lies in your variable fields, which seems to be a json data

Comment: With async set to true, it throws an error if you refresh it a lot.

Comment: This has something to do with jQuery noConflict. I am sure it is a timing issue.